# FsUnit.xUnit FSharp.Core and xunit.assert assembly binding

Tags: f#, nuget, xunit, fsunit

I am taking my first steps with F# and testing with FsUnit.xUnit.
In Visual Studio 2017 I set up a brand new F# project and add a test project.
To the test project I NuGet FsUnit.xUnit 3.0.0 and then NuGet FsUnit.xUnit.Sample.
Everything builds.
Tests then fail with

```
System.IO.FileLoadException
Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
at ApplicationLibraryTest.Tests.Given a LightBulb that has had its state set to true.when I ask whether it is On it answers true.()
```

After reading the [FsUnit Homepage](http://fsprojects.github.io/FsUnit/) and [FsUnit Issues](https://github.com/fsprojects/fsunit/issues/23) I add an `app.config` with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="FSharp.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.999.999.999" newVersion="4.4.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

As FSharp.Core.dll in `bin/debug` is version 4.4.1.0.

Running tests again gives

```
System.IO.FileLoadException
Could not load file or assembly 'xunit.assert, Version=2.1.0.3179, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8d05b1bb7a6fdb6c' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at ApplicationLibraryTest.Tests.Given a LightBulb that has had its state set to true.when I ask whether it is On it answers true.() in D:\git\ApplicationLibrary\ApplicationLibraryTest\FsUnitSample.fs:line 18
```

So i add another redirect in `app.config` as follows

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="xunit.assert" publicKeyToken="8d05b1bb7a6fdb6c" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-999.999.999.999" newVersion="2.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

version 2.2.0.0 being the version of xunit.assert that i find in `bin\debug`.

Yet again the tests fail. This time with

```
System.IO.FileLoadException
Could not load file or assembly 'xunit.assert, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8d05b1bb7a6fdb6c' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at ApplicationLibraryTest.Tests.Given a LightBulb that has had its state set to true.when I ask whether it is On it answers true.() in D:\git\ApplicationLibrary\ApplicationLibraryTest\FsUnitSample.fs:line 18

System.IO.FileLoadException
Could not load file or assembly 'xunit.assert, Version=2.1.0.3179, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8d05b1bb7a6fdb6c' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
  Exception doesn't have a stacktrace
```

Test Project Details:
Target F# runtime: 4.4.1.0

Target Framework: 4.6.2

What am i doing wrong? Is this a configuration issue or is there something that i'm missing that's stopping FsUnit.xUnit from running tests?

Comment: Normally you shouldn't need to add binding redirects manually. I believe NuGet should add them automatically. Try removing your binding redirects and running [Add-BindingRedirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/ps-ref-add-bindingredirect)

Comment: I did already try that. But tried again anyway. I removed the redirects leaving just an empty app.config in the test project. Then in the package manager console i did Add-BindingRedirect to the test project. There was _no_ change in the app.config. It remained empty. Tests obviously still fail.

Comment: Also tried tip from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46172340/why-doesnt-bindingredirect-affect-fsharp-core-version?rq=1) post. Placed app.config into the `bin\debug` folder (which i take to be the execution folder that it refers to?). Again, tests fail.

Comment: Seems like a nuget problem. I've added a nuget tag so this may get more appropriate attention. You may also want to try using paket instead of nuget.